# Adaboost for 3D Input data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, optimization

I want to do a text classification problem for which I want to train use [Adaboost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) Classifier from sklearn using a Keras estimator. I do know how to use the Keras wrappers for using sklearn functions. So that is not the problem. I have a 3D input data (number_sentences, number_words, features) and when I checked the source code of Adaboost, it shows that X can be only 1D or 2D.

- Why is that so?
- Is there any other way for me to use Adaboost for 3D    input data?

Comment: It is still an open issue on sklearn.. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7767

Comment: Yes, I had actually raised it there after not getting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adaboost doesn't care about the order of the features, so no matter how many dimensions your samples have, you can just flatten them. Flattening them gives you a 2D X with shape (n_samples, n_features) which you can feed to the Adaboost classifier.

Comment: but if I do change the X to be passed onto the Adaboost, the base_estimator which is Keras RNN in my case might throw an error because it expects a 3D Input

Comment: Could you add a piece of code to you question that shows how you're trying to combine the keras RNN with the Adaboost classifier?